# Factorial calculator using functions in C

Tags: c

I am learning about functions and how to call upon them and use them in class. I don't quite understand where I've gone wrong here. I know that there are some mistakes around the `int main` part. I have asked my teacher and he is reluctant on giving me an example that would solve my problems or help me out. I think my main problem is at `factorial_result = factorial();`

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void mystamp(void)
{
    printf("My name is John Appleseed\n");
    printf("My lab time is 12:30 on Sunday\n");
    return;
}

int getnum(void)
{
    int local_var;
    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", local_var);
    return(local_var);
}

int factorial(void)
{
    int x,f=1,local_var;

    for(x=1; x <= local_var; x++)
    f = f * x;
    return(f);
}

int main(void)
{
    int result;
    int factorial_result;
    mystamp();
    result = getnum();
    factorial_result = factorial();
    printf("You typed %d\n", result);
    printf("The factorial is %d\n", factorial_result);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Learn about scope of variables. `local_var` is not global.

Comment: Your `local_var` is never initialized, in the `factorial()` function.

Comment: C and C ++ are 2 different languages. Do not abuse the tags, just indicate the language you use.

Comment: And, as a general rule of thumb, give your variables meaningful names.

Comment: The main issue has been pointed out but when asking such questions try to narrow it down to the part that is the problem and explicitly state what is happening and what you expect to happen. It cannot always be guessed

Comment: Note that a 32-bit integer cannot store factorials larger than 12! and a 64-bit integer cannot store factorials larger than 20!

Comment: Still new to the site and to programming in general. My teacher told me to save it as a .cpp and is asking us to use a C++ compiler. Just assumed the two were similar. Thanks everyone for your comments, especially about the variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare local_var as a global variable and do:

```
local_var = getnum();
```

**OR**

Change `main()` to:

```
int main(void)
{
    int result;
    int factorial_result;
    mystamp();
    result = getnum();
    factorial_result = factorial(result);
    printf("You typed %d\n", result);
    printf("The factorial is %d\n", factorial_result);
    return;
}
```

And `factorial()` to:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int x,f=1,local_var=n;

    for(x=1; x <= local_var; x++)
    f = f * x;
    return(f);
}
```

Comment: Not sure where I got the & idea from, thanks for clearing that up.
I didn't think about adding local_var as global variable and neither did my teacher, is that something that needs to be done?

Thanks very much for your answer, it has cleared alot up for me :)

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Comment: If you want to access a variable from other functions, either you pass it as a parameter or declare it as a global.

Comment: It's all making sense :')

Comment: Yeah you need to tell the function that this variable exists with its value/address.

Answer (score 1):

Your factorial should be calculated based on the input( i.e in your case `int result` ).

So, your method `factorial()` should looks as follows :

```
int factorial( int number )
{
  int factorial_value = 1;
  while( number > 0 )
  {
     factorial_value *= number;
     number--;
  }
  return factorial_value;
}
```

Then, the correct factorial would be returned and printed accordingly ! Regarding the scope of the variables that you have used, see the comments under your question.

Comment: and call like `factorial_result = factorial(result);`

Comment: "Then, the correct factorial would be returned and printed accordingly", that is if integer doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int factorial(int);
int main()
{
int num;
int result;
printf("Enter a number to find it's Factorial: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
if (num < 0)
{
printf("Factorial of negative number not possible\n");
}
else
{
result = factorial(num);
printf("The Factorial of %d is %d.\n", num, result);
}
return 0;
}
int factorial(int num)
{
if (num == 0 || num == 1)
{
return 1;
}
else
{
return(num * factorial(num - 1));
}
}
```

This is a simple factorial program using recursion calling function !

Answer (score -3):

include

```
int main()
{ 
    int c, n, fact = 1;    
    printf("Enter a number to calculate its factorial\n"); scanf("%d", &n);
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) fact = fact * c;
    printf("Factorial of %d = %d\n", n, fact);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using `include` will give error, and please use proper formatting while posting code.